# Akka actor instance and class

Tags: akka

When the Akka manual refers to an actor, does it mean an *instance* of an Actor subclass? Or is it `Props` that allow creation of multiple actor instances?

So when it says an Actor has a mailbox, does it mean one mailbox per Actor instance, or a single mailbox per multiple instances of the same-`Props` actors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When documentation refers to actor instance, it's an instance of `Actor`, `Props` is just a configuration object. See [scaladocs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.9/#akka.actor.Props)

Think of `Props` as a recipe - meaning that each baked actor instance will be separate and have separate mailbox. For instance, you can configure deployment configuration in both config file (`application.conf`) or in `Props`. See [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/general/configuration.html#Actor_Deployment_Configuration) in addition to example from scaladocs (e.g. `props.withRouter(...)`)

There are two entities that can be referred as an actor:

- Actor instance, or object of `Actor` class is usually referred as an actor. So, when you read 'actor is created' it means that this instance is created
- `ActoRef` is a pointer to the `Actor` (or its mailbox) that is used to interact. As you shouldn't (and will not) interact with Actor instance itself, you will send messages to the `ActorRef`. So, if you read 'send message X to the actor Y' it means that you invoke `!` method on `ActorRef` pointing to actor Y's mailbox.

Comment: But when it refers to just an Actor? Without saying it's an instance. Does it actually mean an instance? As with the mailbox example.

Comment: Updated answer regarding instances and refs